# TFS integration with Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any extension to Visual Studio Code in order to work with TFS?

I have found it working only with Git.

Comment: Unless someone write an extension to do so, you will have to wait till VS Code itself to add that.

Comment: Yes thats what I thought. I have tried VS community 2015 and its great :)

Comment: Someone  requested this issue at [this link](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752390-integrate-with-team-foundation-server). We can vote for it so that the visual studio team support it.